# Need help about binary files

Tags: c

I'm having trouble creating a code that creates a bin file with multiple lines, each one containing 6 values per line. for example:
I'm doing a little project where each line will be a 'password', so my system will load this file and read all passwords from it, when it gets updated and etc.
I havent implemented the way to read the file yet because i'm struggling to manipulate the file. 
This project will be running on linux with GPIO features from Raspberry pi 
so i'm using  Visual Studio for creating the main code.

My current code is:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char keys[4] = { '1', '2', '3', '4' }; // NOT USING
char temp_key[6];

int incl_key() {
    int i;
    FILE *fp;
    char code = "0";
    int control = 0;
    int var_internal = 0;

    fp = fopen("keys.bin", "wb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("\n Error opening file. \n");
    }

    printf("write your sequence <6 digits>:\n");

    do{
        scanf("%s", &temp_key);
        fputs(temp_key, fp);
        fputs("\n", fp);
        control++;
    } while (control < 5);
    fclose(fp);
}

int keys_db() {
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    incl_key();

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is or what your specific trouble is. If you want to organize it as "lines" why is it a binary file?

Comment: Code is writing outside array bounds with `char temp_key[6]; scanf("%s", &temp_key);` and input like `"123456"`.

Comment: Your `temp_key` has six elements, and you have shown us sample data that has six characters. This means that `temp_key` is full when you call `fputs` and does not contain a terminating null character. So `fputs` overruns the array, looking for that null, and you do not know what is written to the file. Define `temp_key` with enough space for the terminating null, and make sure your `scanf` does not read too much.

Comment: You generally `fwrite` and `fread` (or without the file stream library, `write` and `read`) binary files. While you can write a `string` (minus it *nul-terminating* character) to any file with `fputs`, you are writing ASCII characters, not a sequence of integers. (e.g. `1-byte` per `char`, verses a general `4-bytes` per `int`)

Comment: @chux So do you mean that i need to put an extra space for '\0' or '\n' symbols in vector? i just wanted to know if is possible to make each password, with 6 characters to be stored one per line, but my code is strange and i got lost.
If this isnt possible on binary files, how could i navigate through the files to seek a password for example? scan 6 numbers and compare with the user vector, but how?

Comment: Binary files do not have "lines". That is a text file concept. Opening a file in binary mode does nothing other than not apply platform specific text file line-end translation.  That is to say that `'\n'` will be written as a single line-feed, whereas in text mode it will on Windows be translated to carriage-return+line-feed.  On Linux it will have no effect because LF is already the newline convention.  Ultimately it is a binary file if you choose to call it that (all files are binary), but to call it that and write variable length lines of printable strings is an unusual use of the term.

Comment: The point "_This project will be running on linux with GPIO features from Raspberry pi so i'm using Visual Studio for creating the main code._" is largely irrelevant, but entirely non-sequitur in any event.

Answer (score 0):

Array is too small for user input as a *string*.

```
char temp_key[6];
printf("write your sequence <6 digits>:\n");
scanf("%s", &temp_key);   // poor code
```

---

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.

When one types <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, that puts `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, `'4'`, `'5'`, `'6'`, `'\n'` into `stdin`.  `scanf("%s", temp_key);` looks for leading white-space, sees none and then reads the 6 non-white-space chracters and saves those in `temp_key[0]`, `temp_key[1]`,  .... `temp_key[5]`.  Reading the `'\n`' (a white-space), the `"%s"` directs to stop scanning for more, puts the `'\n'` back into `stdin` for later input and *then attempts to append a null character* into `temp_key[6]` to make it a *string*.  But `temp_key[]` is too small for that and so anything may happens - it is *undefined behavior*.  Remaining code is irrelevant.

`scanf("%s", &temp_key);` is improper code for 3 reasons.

1. `&temp_key` passes the address of an array when the address of the first element of the array is needed to match `"%s"`.  Both of those addresses have equivalent values, yet different types.  This itself is *undefined behavior*.  Yet the vast majority of the time, it "works" like the correct `scanf("%s", temp_key);`  (no `&`)
2. `scanf("%s", temp_key);` offers no limitation on how much data is read and as outlined above, entering 6 or more digits results in a buffer overrun and *undefined behavior*.
3. The return value is not checked, so code does not know if things are successful.  `stdin` could have been *closed* (no more input) or other concerns.

Instead use `fgets()` to read a *line* of user input and covert that input into a *string*.

```
#define KEY_N 6
//            key    \n   \0  extra - why be stingy? 
char temp_key[KEY_N + 1 + 1 + 10];

//scanf("%s", &temp_key);
if (fgets(temp_key, sizeof temp_key, stdin)) {
  // user input successfully read!

  temp_key[strcspn(temp_key), "\n"] = '\0'; // lop off potential trailing \n
  if (strlen(temp_key) != KEY_N) Handle_Invalid_Input();
  else GoodToGo();
}
```

---

Code may have other issues too.

E.g.: The `fp` in binary vs text mode along with "running on linux ... so i'm using Visual Studio" has concerns about the expectations of reading "keys.bin" which appears like a text file. For now, what OP is doing concerning that looks OK as long as it is treated a a binary file.