# trying to get rid of a character using strtok in c

Tags: c, strtok

So I need to be able to input a string as a phone number like so: 
(555)-444-3333.
After that I need to use strtok to remove the parentheses and dashes, and convert the strings area code and the rest of the phone number to just integers and print them out all together
My problem is using strtok to get rid of the  ( , because if I don't the area code will just print 0 when it's converted to an int. Here's what I have:

```
int main()
{
phone[14];
int* area_code;
int* digits;
int* i, j;

printf("Enter a phone number: ");
scanf("%s", phone);

strtok( phone, "(" );
area_code = strtok( phone, ")" );
j = atoi(area_code);

printf("%d", j);

while((digits = strtok(NULL, "-")) != NULL )
{
i = atoi(digits);
printf("%d", digits);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"(555)-444-3333"` is too long for `phone[14];`  Needs 15.  `scanf("%s", phone);
` is then _undefined behavior_ (UB).  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47354083/2410359) may help.

Comment: All usage of `atoi` should be replaced with `strtol`.  It needs more parameters but the better error-handling alone is worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is right here:

```
strtok( phone, "(" );
area_code = strtok( phone, ")" );
```

Because the second call passes a non-NULL pointer, it doesn't continue processing the first string, it starts over beginning at the pointer passed, which is now a string of length zero.

In any case, overwriting the string you are parsing is bad style.  If you use `strtol`, a single call will give you BOTH the numeric value of a group of digits AND a pointer following the digits, where you can start processing the next group of digits.

But if you just are going to print the digits back out, you don't need a numeric conversion at all.  Just remove all punctuation.

---

Despite having 5/6 characters the same, `strtok` is not part of the `str`-`to`-*x* family of functions.  Those are `strtol` returning a long integer, and `strtod` returning a double.

Answer (score 0):

In your `strtok` calls, specify the delimiters as `"()-"`.

Best of luck.